# no focus event for jquery datePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've got the next code:

```
$("#fecha_fin, #bf_fin").click(function(){
    if( $("#fecha_inicio").val() == "" ){
        crearModal( "Alerta", 
                    getMessage("/js/buscador/buscadores.js", "11", codidi, 'Por favor, seleccione la fecha de inicio del hotel.'));

        $("#fecha_fin").val("");
    }else if(($("#fecha_fin").val() == "") || (this.id == "bf_fin")){
        var diasASumar = dif_dias("hoy", "fecha_inicio") + 1;
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +diasASumar);
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("show");
    }
});

$("#fecha_fin").focus(function(){
    if( $("#fecha_inicio").val() == "" ){
        crearModal( "Alerta", 
                    getMessage("/js/buscador/buscadores.js", "11", codidi, 'Por favor, seleccione la fecha de inicio del hotel.'));

        $("#fecha_fin").val("");
    }else if(($("#fecha_fin").val() == "") || (this.id == "bf_fin")){
        var diasASumar = dif_dias("hoy", "fecha_inicio") + 1;
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +diasASumar);
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("show");
    }
});
```

The fact is that when the focus event occurs, instead of the click one, the line making the defaultDate doesn't works. No error, simply it doesn't make what it is supposed to do. But when the event is the click one, it goes perfect.

Can anyone give a direction, please?

Comment: Ok, I'll make an edit of the code, deleting what it isn't intended to be.

Answer (score 1):

The most clean code is as follows:

```
$("#fecha_fin, #bf_fin").click(function(){
        var diasASumar = dif_dias("hoy", "fecha_inicio") + 1;
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +diasASumar);
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("show");
    }
});

$("#fecha_fin").focus(function(){
        var diasASumar = dif_dias("hoy", "fecha_inicio") + 1;
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", +diasASumar);
        $("#fecha_fin").datepicker("show");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `+` sign before your variable `diasASumar`. That is not required.

Comment: The JQuery documentation says I must put that + sign before de days I want to establish. Anyway, it doesn't fix the problem.